# For this simple program what will be the output just after lexcial analysis?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, lexical-analysis

For a simple `C` program like :

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
   int first,second,sum;
   first = 10;
   second = 20;
   sum = first + second;
   printf("%d\n",sum);
}
```

what will be the output after the first phase of compiler *which is Lexcial Analysis* ?

Answer (score 4):

Lexical analysis produces a stream of *tokens*. Ignoring the preprocessor for now, the output would be something like

```
KEYWORD int
IDENTIFIER main
LPAREN
RPAREN
LBRACE
KEYWORD int
IDENTIFIER first
COMMA
...
```

Obviously, the actual output is dependent on your compiler.

Comment: Can you please explain the output

Comment: LPAREN would be "(", RPARAN would be ")", etc.

Comment: Why have you written one output as `KEYWORD int` and not just `int` ?

Comment: The first column is the "type" of the token, and the second column is the "value", if applicable. Some lexers will output `INT`, `FLOAT`, `CONST`, etc. as separate token classes. My output is purely illustrative; for "actual" output consult your favourite compiler's internals.

Answer (score 1):

There is no output. The first phase may be lexical analysis but that doesn't mean it is an entire distinct pass with an output which forms the input to the next stage. The parser calls the lexical analyser via function calls.